# Use Custom XML Layout with GuidedStepSupportFragment For Smart TV UI Design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv

How can I use a custom xml layout file with `GuidedStepSupportFragment` with leanback library.

**I need use the custom view into right and left both sides with some action**. How can I achieve this? I am new to smart TV development.

I need some this type of more customized design :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`GuidedStepFragment` is composed of 2 parts, `Guidance` (the side at left) and `Actions` (the side at right). You can provide layout for both of them by overriding `onProvideLayoutId` inside the corresponding `Stylist`.

For example if you want to change `Guidance` you can use this code:

```
    @Override
    public GuidanceStylist onCreateGuidanceStylist() {
        return new GuidanceStylist() {
            @Override
            public int onProvideLayoutId() {
                // return your cutom layout
                return R.layout.layout_custom_guidance;
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Guidance guidance) {
                View guidanceView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, guidance);
                // You can access Views here
                return guidanceView;
            }
        };
    }
```

`Actions` part consists of several `GuidedAction` item, and for each you can provide the layout in a similar way:

```
    @Override
    public GuidedActionsStylist onCreateActionsStylist() {
        return new GuidedActionsStylist() {
            @Override
            public int onProvideItemLayoutId() {
                // return your custom layout for each GuidedAction item
                return R.layout.layout_custom_action_item;
            }

            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent);
                // Access Views here
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };
    }
```

For your specific `Actions` side you can insert one `Action` with your intended layout.

Comment: What if we want to avoid at all the GuidedActions? It is possible?

Comment: @carrasc0 I'm not sure. You my add one action with your custom layout.

Comment: How does `onProvideLayoutId` determine what action is currently active, so that it can replace the guidance for a specific action?

Comment: @strarsis It does not know the active Action. If you override it the layout for all actions will be changed.

Comment: @mahdi: Thanks! Maybe I am totally misunderstanding the guided steps pattern. I first thought that the onboarding UI can also offer settings to the user, but it is rather meant to present features of the app.

Is the guided steps UI intended for offering options to the user? E.g. the user should be able to toggle or enable one specific option in the app - how would one do that? Add that option as an action?

Comment: @strarsis It's possible to add different types of actions in GuidedStep, and you can use different view for different action types. Take a look at the usage of `viewType` in `GuidedActionsStylist` source code to find out how it handles types and its regarding views.

Comment: @mahdi: Have you also encountered this issue? When the `GuidedStepSupportFragment`  is swapped using `add(parentFragmentManager, FinishStepFragment())`, the new fragment is not padded anymore, as the initial one. But I am using the same code for creating the other `GuidedStepSupportFragment` that are swapped in.

Comment: @strarsis No, I haven't.

Comment: @mahdi: I prepared a minimal reproducible example: https://github.com/strarsis/android-guidedstepsupportfragment-issue
Clone it into Android Studio, then launch the app directly in an Android TV emulator, use the action to go to the 2nd guidance and notice that the padding is missing there.

Comment: @strarsis Sorry for my late reply! I couldn't find a problem in your code. Could you ask a new independent question in SO for better visibility?

Comment: @mahdi: I created a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77773407/android-tv-leanback-guidedstepsupportfragment-missing-incorrect-padding